# Weird Google Analytics Issues

Tags: google-analytics

I have several properties set up with Google Analytics. Today when I signed in to Google and went to the Google Analytics homepage, it displayed a “Welcome” page, as if I was a first-time user. My analytics were nowhere to be seen. I was finally able to access my analytics account by using a different browser that still apparently had my login information cached. But it displayed as follows:
**[myname]%[myDomain]@gtempaccount.com**

Note the percent sign between my name and domain. And what's the gtempaccount.com all about?

Using this weird login, I was able to successfully access my information. But I'm concerned about the next time I attempt to log in. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

In troubleshoot issues with Google Accounts, you can read that you have a conflicting account.

**How a conflicting account is created**

A conflicting account is a personal Google Account that was created using the email address of a G Suite account. For this reason, any G Suite user could have two accounts with the same email address.

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/181526?hl=en

Try this to fix:
https://support.google.com/accounts/troubleshooter/1699308?visit_id=637394312549787556-604649055&hl=en&rd=1